# Passing arguments to PyGAD fitness function

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I'm curious how you send arguments to the fitness function in PyGAD i.e

```
import pygad

def fitness_function(solution, solution_idx,num):
    print(num+10)
    return sum(solution)

ga_instance = pygad.GA(num_generations=1,
                       num_parents_mating=2,
                       sol_per_pop=3,
                       num_genes=4,
                       fitness_func=fitness_function,

                       init_range_low=5,
                       init_range_high=15,args=(5,))
```

What I expected from this piece of code was that I'd print 15 every time the fitness function would be called (just to make sure passing parameters was working correctly).

but instead I get

```
 python gaex.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gaex.py", line 14, in <module>
    init_range_high=15,arg=(5,))
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'args'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to achieve. I see in the docs https://pygad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/README_pygad_ReadTheDocs.html#pygad-ga-class that GA does not accept `args` as a parameter, and defines strictly how the `fitness_function` should be defined.

Are you, perhaps, trying to parametrize the fitness_function, so that you could change it's behaviour by changing a variable?

Comment: Hey psarka, in all other optimization libraries not only can you pass the variable input, but arguments that you can used to calculate the objective function. This library is the only one that seems to not have that support which is very weird to me...

Comment: It is not too strange, as you won't be able to change the arguments when the genetic algorithm starts to run. Which means that your arguments will be constant. Which means that you can set them in another way (I'll write an answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your fitness function parametrizable like that:

```py
def fitness_function_factory(num):

    def fitness_function(solution, solution_idx):
        print(num + 10)
        return sum(solution)

    return fitness_function
```

Then give it to the GA it like that:

```py
ga_instance = pygad.GA(num_generations=1,
                       ...
                       fitness_func=fitness_function_factory(5),
                       ...
                       init_range_high=15)
```